# Docker build different in Github Actions

Tags: docker, github, pip, github-actions

When I build my docker file locally and push my application runs correctly. However when I Build through github actions I get an error that 'flask' is not installed.

It seems that the pip install step does nothing in Github actions - it just shows:

```
Step 8/13 : RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r /app/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 6b0816c1bdc8
Removing intermediate container 6b0816c1bdc8
```

However on my local i get the full pip install output..

Is there something I am missing with Github Actions?

DockerFile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ARG DB_PASSWORD

RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

ADD ./requirements.txt /app
ADD ./src /app


RUN cat /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

ENV DEBUG=false
ENV FLASE_DEBUG=false
ENV TESTING=false

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Action Step:

```
- name: Build docker image and push to ECR
  run: /bin/bash $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/scripts/build_and_push.sh
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.aws_access_key_id }}
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.aws_secret_access_key }}
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "eu-west-1"
```

Build Script:

```
pipenv run pip freeze > requirements.txt

aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin {{ ECR Address}}

docker build -t {{ image name }} .
```

Comment: Can you please share the requirements.txt file as well? Also, did you try to install flask before running pip install on requirements file?

Comment: You could also use this Action to install your python packages from the requirements.txt file: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pip-installer